# How to create custom data view/page based on a List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list, custom-view

I have standard custom List with Companies, their Capabilities, Status and a Count column. I want to create a custom data view/page showing this in a neat and tidy way. The left column will be all the Companies, the top row will be the Capabilites and then each cell in between will be the Counts of Status types for each Companies' Capabilities.